# Integrate Small Calendar (datepicker) and Timeline with fullCalendar

Tags: jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

I want to implement two features apart from the ones in Basic View of FullCalendar. The inspiration is Google calendar. Here is what I want:

[image: http://i42.tinypic.com/1ffm7k.png]

Although I couldn't find these two features in FullCalendar documentation I'd still like to confirm if FullCalendar supports these features.
If not, please feel free to share any suggestions on how I should implement them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish the time line with the code [here](http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=143), and you can use date picker and link it with fullcalendar to create the small calendar on the left. Here is how to implement it...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        inline: true,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            var d = new Date(dateText);
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', d);
        }
    }); 
}
```

This will force fullCalendar to go to what ever date is selected in the jquery date picker.

Answer (score -1):

Also now, you can omit the need of minor datepicker just for the sake of navigating to some specific date by using navigation links feature of FullCalendar. with that, you can navigate to any date from month view e.g

```
<FullCalendar 
  ...
  navLinks={true}
>
```